# Adding text to beginning of file with contents in the file

Tags: ios, filehandle

I have this file, it contains:

"AAAAAAA"

I want to add "11111" to the file above. I tried two different calls, BOTH with seekToFileOffset:0:

fileHandleForWritingAtPath:

"11111AA"

Some items at the front parts of the file are truncated (gone)

I also tried:

fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:

It also ended with:

"11111AA"

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, depending on your skill level

- rewrite the file with a new name, delete the original file, and rename the newly written file to the original name.
- rewrite the file in place. For example, using a 1K buffer, you do this by starting at the end, read the last 1K, and rewrite at the same location+an offset corresponding to the number of bytes to insert. Repeat for all previous data. When you get to the front of the file, you will have moved all the data by the desired offset and can then write the new data.